# Sharepoint online CSOM generate list item display url

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a file list inside desktop app thats fetched from the sharepoint online document library. What i want to do is to provide a posibility to show that file in the browser. But i'm not able to generate proper url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a csom code snippet to get file url in a document library:

```
           using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://zheguo.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/"))
            {

                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                List targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

                ListItemCollection ItemCol = targetList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                ctx.Load(ItemCol);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in ItemCol)
                    {
                        if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(new Uri(ctx.Url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + item["FileRef"]);
                        }

                    }
            }
```

Reference:

[Getting the Absolute URL of a File in CSOM](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/getting-the-absolute-url-of-a-file-in-csom/)